# Android plugin based app?

Tags: android, plugins

I have a application which I have divided in multiple module.
Every module is having different functionality for example.

Dlna module :- it has the functionality of reading dlna server and fetch their data and create the object for my project.

RdioModule :- it has the functionality of fetching data from rdio server and create the object for my project.

Now what I want is to divide my application in multiple parts, and install the module functionality as a plugin in app.

Is it possible, if yes please suggest me how I can achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible, if yes please suggest me how I can achieve it.

It's possible, however is's not that easy, I have read some articles about it recently and you may check it out here, hope it may help you:
https://github.com/singwhatiwanna/dynamic-load-apk